# Malformed message captured in Wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark

I have been using wireshark for a project I am working on, and I noticed that a lot of, seemingly malformed, messages are being send over my wlan0 interface. I am not sure where they come from, so I was hoping that someone could shed some light on this.

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell XPS 13.

The only thing I can think of is posting one of these messages here:

```
0000   5c f8 a1 96 0f 5f 00 1e 0b 70 b0 98 00 4c 50 03  \...._...p...LP.
0010   00 20 00 00 00 00 1e e0 1f e8 a3 93 99 f4 41 9d  . ............A.
0020   93 76 82 9d 4e 99 da 43 cb bc 29 86 83 9c 8e f4  .v..N..C..).....
0030   20 df a9 4f e9 3e df a1 32 2c 59 e3 e6 a6 8a 97   ..O.>..2,Y.....
0040   40 ce fc a2 74 f2 a7 5d ce 12 e5 69 74 ec 4c e1  @...t..]...it.L.
0050   8e cd d3 19 92 b0 84 12 29 6f                    ........)o
```

A lot of these messages seem to use the LLC (Logical link control) protocol, though not all. Any suggestions are welcome.